# Hi im trying to use kmsi in a custom policy using self asserted page content definition how can I implement add kmsi to it?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Im working on a custom b2c policy  and want to enable kmsi in it.
I followed the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in) to implement kmsi

But the customer login requires certain custom fields while signing in . hence I cant use the combined signup/signin flow . How to add KMSI in a self asserted custom page ?

also how to add it in the UI since the kms meta-tag isnt supported in self asserted pages pages(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately right now, KMSI only works against the combined signup/signin flow, which ties you to username/password UI.

Comment: so if i want to have a long running log-in session in spa what are my options since the session cookie only stays for 24 hours

Comment: Configure a rolling session, and call acquireTokenSilent() every X minutes. That will keep the cookie rolling until the user signs out, as long as they keep the app open.